# Unset a php array element via javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

Suppose I have a php session array:

```
$_SESSION[MyItems]=Array('A'=>"Apple", 'B'=>"Brownie", 'C'="Coin"))
```

that is used to display items on a page visited by a user and I want the user to be able to drop one or more of the items from the display using a client-side javascript function (ie. something that hides the item or changes the div to display=none...I get how to do that sort of thing now.) rather than involving a trip back to the server/page reload.

How can I simultaneously drop the item from the `$_SESSION[MyItems]` array when the javascript drops the item from view (ie so it does not reappear if the page reloads?

I think maybe the task would involve converting the whole `$_SESSION[MyItems]` array into a javascript array, dropping the item(s) from that, and then having the javascript version of the array somehow overwrite `$_SESSION[MyItems]`.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

All the session data are stored in cookies and cookies are accessable to both client and server. So you can surely do this by editing the cookies but this practice should be avoided and `you should not do this` because session is meant for server side only.

hope it helps :)

Comment: I think I have gotten into a bad habit of using $_SESSION arrays unnecessarily.  Suppose we forget $_SESSION and assume we are simply talking about $MyItems?  As I reflect on this, I don't think I have to use $_SESSION for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not so simple, because PHP runs on the server-side, the `$_SESSION` object from PHP is not available on the client-side, where javascript runs.

you would need to put something like this in the head of your template (assuming it is a .php-file with HTML-content):

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //parse PHP to json-string for javascript initialisation
            var MyItems = <?php echo json_encode ($_SESSION[MyItems], true); ?>;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Then you would have a copy of the PHP `$_SESSION` object called `MyItems` in javascript.
But changes made to the JS-object wont be saved to the PHP-object. 
To do this you could use JQuery´s [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post ("target.php", { "MyItems": JSON.stringify (MyItems) }, function (result) {

    if (result == "true")
        //do something
    else
        //do something else

});
```

With your `target.php` file looking like this:

```
<?php

    $_SESSION['MyItems'] = json_decode ($_POST['MyItems']);
    echo "true";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. As I commented to the prior response, I probably don't need to involve $_SESSION at all.  I probably will use $.post to add/drop values in a server-side database, but I think I see a glimmer of how this takes place in your response.  Getting too tired to code this tonight but will give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: You can save the data where ever you want, The sending keeps the same. ;) good night mate.